# 'val_accuracy' and 'accuracy' missing in fitted model history Tensorflow (YOLO)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im trying to retrain YOLOv4 model with custom dataset. It supposed to detect and predict car body type such as sedan, suv, etc.

here is the training function:

```
def model_train(data_dir:str, model_dir:str, version:str, epochs:int = 100, class_path:str = '', annot_path:str = ''):
    model_filename = 'epoch_{epoch:02d}-val_loss-{val_loss:.4f}.hdf5'

    # Path & Directory
    # Data
    annot_path = annot_path if annot_path else os.path.join(data_dir, 'annot.txt')
    FOLDER_PATH = os.path.join(data_dir, 'image')
    class_name_path = class_path if class_path else os.path.join(data_dir, 'car_classes.txt')
    # Model
    logdir = os.path.join(model_dir, 'logs', version)
    checkpoint_dir = os.path.join(model_dir, 'checkpoint', version)
    checkpoint_path = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, model_filename)

    # Training data
    train_lines, val_lines = read_annotation_lines(annot_path, test_size=0.3)
    data_gen_train = DataGenerator(train_lines, class_name_path, FOLDER_PATH)
    data_gen_val = DataGenerator(val_lines, class_name_path, FOLDER_PATH)

    # Model object initialization
    model = Yolov4(weight_path=None, class_name_path=class_name_path)

    # Callbacks
    rLrCallBack = callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
        monitor = 'val_loss',
        factor = 0.1,
        patience = 5,
        verbose = 1)
    tbCallBack = callbacks.TensorBoard(
        log_dir = logdir,
        histogram_freq = 0,
        write_graph = True,
        write_images = False)
    mcCallBack_loss = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        checkpoint_path,
        monitor = 'val_loss',
        verbose = 1,
        save_best_only = True,
        save_weights_only = False,
        mode = 'auto',
        period = 100)
    esCallBack = callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor = 'val_loss',
        mode = 'min',
        verbose = 1,
        patience = 25)

    # Fitting
    model = model.fit(
        data_gen_train,
        initial_epoch=0,
        epochs=epochs, 
        val_data_gen=data_gen_val,
        callbacks=[
            rLrCallBack,
            tbCallBack,
            mcCallBack_loss,
            esCallBack]
    )

    return model
```

YOLOv4 and DataGenerator class is from https://github.com/taipingeric/yolo-v4-tf.keras

The problem is, there is no accuracy history to plot

```
model.history.keys()
# dict_keys(['loss', 'val_loss', 'lr'])
```

Comment: Accuracy is not a metric that is used in object detection.

Answer (score 0):

The [compilation of the model](https://github.com/taipingeric/yolo-v4-tf.keras/blob/master/models.py#L83) is done as follows:

```py
self.training_model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3),
                            loss={'yolo_loss': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred})
```

That means that there is no argument `metrics`, so you cannot get a metric if you do not change that line of code to something like:

```py
self.training_model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3),
                            loss={'yolo_loss': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred},
                            metrics=tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy())
```

Comment: There is no accuracy metric that makes sense in object detection, that is why there is no accuracy metric in the original code.

Comment: got an error if i added `metrics=tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()` or `metrics=['accuracy`]` as compile parameter.

@Dr.Snoopy so i actually don't need accuracy metric?

Comment: @ZEDT As I said, accuracy is not used in object detection, so you do not need it, what makes you think you have to use it?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I think i could use it to evaluate the training process just like in object classification model training. Im new in object detection. Thank you for your information.

Comment: @ZEDT That is not a good motivation, you need to think about your metrics, which metrics are relevant for a given task, mAP is the main metric used in object detection.